# Can you use html 5 - viblast audio player for ionic andriod for hls streams

Tags: android, html, audio, ionic-framework, http-live-streaming

Can i use html5 audio viblast player for ionic android i am using html 5 audio player to play my hls stream it works on iphone but not on android.

what my question is does html5 work to play hls on android?

this is my code:

```
<audio id="player" src="http:\/\/stream.tvstartup.net\/barakyah-vod\/play\/mp3:sestore1\/barakyah\/newsystem\/audios\/hottestjams_sdfsdf_1474995480509.mp3\/playlist.m3u8" data-viblast-key="N8FjNTQ3NDdhZqZhNGI5NWU5ZTI=" controls></audio>
```

all help is appreicate thank you

Comment: any help hello anyone

Comment: I'm not sure about that player under Android... Android can play HLS on its own but it depends on the Android version, and it's buggy.  In any case, you need to get rid of those backslashes in the URL.

Comment: ok i will get rid of the backslashes in the Url do you know of any other audio player that will work for iphone and android?